# java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject in android

Tags: java, android, json

It is a question that has been asked many times but i didn't find any solution from the answers that they gave.

Below is a code i wrote to read a json file i have in raw folder to get all the questions under my questions object but keeps returning that error. i searched but did not find any that helped me with my problem. Will appreciate that help thanks.

```
private void IterateQuestions() throws JSONException {

        obj = (JSONObject) new JSONTokener(loadJSONFromAsset()).nextValue();
       // obj = new JSONObject(loadJSONFromAsset());
       // questionMark = obj.getJSONObject("questions");


        Iterator<String> iter = obj.keys();
        // String check = questionMark.toString();
        // System.out.println("dnt be stubborn "+check + " this is check");
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            // get the object corresponding to the next key
            JSONObject questions= obj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(iter.next()));

            String questions= country.getString("questions");
            Log.e("","questions: "+countryName);
            System.out.println("this is countryName "+countryName);

        }

    }
```

part of the code in my json below

```
   {"questions":{"59006": {
  "qid": "59006",
  "topic": "0",
  "instructions": "",
  "text": "<p>Y<span>&epsilon;nya nn</span><span>ɔbae<span>&epsilon; kuo yi firi okuafo</span></span><span>ɔ h</span><span>ɔ</span></p>",
  "resource": "",
  "qtype": "SINGLE",
  "confirmed": "1",
  "public": "1",
  "flagged": "0",
  "updated_at": "2014-07-14 12:12:38",
  "rating": 0,
  "answers": [
    {
      "id": "254130",
      "text": "<p>Gyeene, nkyene, mako</p>",
      "value": "0",
      "solution": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "254131",
      "text": "<p>Mako, bor<span>ɔ</span>de<span>&epsilon;, nyaadewa</span></p>",
      "value": "1",
      "solution": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "254132",
      "text": "<p>Nkuruma, abor<span>ɔ</span>b<span>&epsilon;, dawuro</span></p>",
      "value": "0",
      "solution": ""
    },
    {
      "id": "254133",
      "text": "<p>Bankye, adua, s<span>ɔs<span>ɔ</span></span></p>",
      "value": "0",
      "solution": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

}
}

Comment: do you have logcat output of the error?

Comment: `String.valueOf(iter.next())` The `String.valueOf` part is not necessary, because `next()` returns a `String` value.

Comment: "answers" in JSON is a JSONArray and you have no logic in your code for that

Comment: `JSONObject questions` and then `String questions` ... I don't think that will work ... check if the String really should be named `questions`.

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile, you have 2 variables named questions, and variables countryName and country that are not declared anywhere. Please check yourself before you wreck yourself...

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Because qid,topic,instructions,... is not JSONObject's but you are trying to convert it to JSONObject using following line:

```
JSONObject questions= obj.getJSONObject(String.valueOf(iter.next()));
```

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10086809/android-json-parser-getting-the-same-value-everytime]

Comment: @SoftServe His JSON structure is different, therefore his `getJSONObject` calls are correct there.

Comment: @SoftServe This doesn't help much if you don't post the code you're really working with. The current code won't compile and not only because you've omitted some parts.